# Observer for all order creation in frontend and admin

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, event-observer, magento-1

I have a problem with observer. I want to send order data to somewhere after creating that order. I need to make it for all possible ways of creating an order (frontend and backend).

Observer for `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` is working fine, but i need it even for creating it in administration. This is an example of my `config.xml` (first event works):

```
<global>
    <events>
        <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            <observers>
                <postDataFromOrderToServer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>PixelDesign_DataResender_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>postDataFromOrderToServer</method>
                </postDataFromOrderToServer>
            </observers>
        </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
    </events>     
</global>
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data>
            <observers>
                <postDataFromOrderToServer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>PixelDesign_DataResender_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>postDataFromOrderToServer</method>
                </postDataFromOrderToServer>
            </observers>
        </adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sales_order_place_after`, it is dispatched right after an order is placed whether from the frontend or the backend.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but it still not work.

Comment: I tried : `<global>  <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <postDataFromOrderToServer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>PixelDesign_DataResender_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>postDataFromOrderToServer</method>
                    </postDataFromOrderToServer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>

        </events>     
    </global>`